# Checking ReadKey against Enum

Tags: c#, if-statement, console, enumeration

I have this enum for all four possible arrow key presses

`enum Direction{up=ConsoleKey.UpArrow, left=Consolekey.LeftArrow,...};`

`private ConsoleKeyInfo userSelect;`

```
private bool mQuit;
```

I then have

```
     public void getUserInput()
     {
        userSelect = Console.ReadKey()

        if (userSelect.Key == ConsoleKey.Escape)
        {
            mQuit = true;
        }
       else if(userSelect.Key == "check if key press is value in enumeration")
       {
        //implementation
       }
    }
```

Can't work out what the code would be to check "if Key press is one of the values in enum"
Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

```
else if(Enum.IsDefined(typeof(Direction), userSelect.Key)) {
    //Logic
}
```

Comment: Isn't it: `else if(Enum.IsDefined(typeof(Direction), userSelect.Key)) {
    //Logic
}`

Comment: Using comments to ask a user to accept your answer is prohibited.  Please refrain from doing so in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You can use cast to solve this problem.

```
if (userSelect.Key == (ConsoleKey)myEnum)
{

}
```